# Replication Factor in Hadoop BIG data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

Suppose i have 1TB of data and set the replication factor to 2,then it makes 2 replicas so do I need 3TB overall space for my entire cluster -1TB for original and 2TB for replicas or just 2 TB?

Answer (score 1):

Just 2TB - the replication factor includes all copies of the data.

Comment: Sure,ty.Also,Hadoop works on WRite once read multiple times.Does that mean that we can write data only once initially while loading it in the system and then perform only read operations on the data?

Comment: HDFS doesn't allow in place updates (other than appends) to existing files. You can effectively do an update by creating a modified copy and replacing the original.

Comment: Does that mean that its better to use Cassandra if we have to make constant updates,Also,what difference does it make if after every time we make an update,it replicates & replaces the original one,does this have any memory issues or any other.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but if you need to do constant updates on a Hadoop cluster then often the best solution is HBase.

Comment: If a name node crashes,do we have to stop all our data processing and then manually go and get it up working,or if we're using Cloudera latest ver.and if it crashes then it automatically names a secondary name node,does the data processing stop at any time during this crash.?